# Golang Redis error on heroku

Tags: heroku, go, redis

I am having a hard time on this one because I cannot reproduce it locally. Intention originally was to test if a Redis connection is accessible from a go method if so continue else inform.

In my code:

```
if os.Getenv("REDISTOGO_URL") != "" {
    host, password = parseRedistogoUrl()
} else {
    host = "tcp:localhost:6379"
    password = ""
}

db := 0

redis = godis.New(host, db, password)

// Try to set a "dummy" value:
err = redis.Set("INIT", time.Now().UTC())
```

With a Redis server available locally this executes without an error, but fails when on heroku.

What makes the problem more interesting is that if the last line (with `err`) is commented out then the next `redis.Set` in the program succeeds, which indicates that the server is accessible later on, but not "just after" the instanciation. Any ideas on how I should resolve this? Is `godis.New(...)` running asynchronously?

Update: This is the parsing function currently used from https://gist.github.com/TheDudeWithTheThing/6468746:

```
func ParseRedistogoUrl() (string, string) {
  redisUrl := os.Getenv("REDISTOGO_URL")
  redisInfo, _ := url.Parse(redisUrl)
  server := redisInfo.Host
  password := ""
  if redisInfo.User != nil {
    password, _ = redisInfo.User.Password()
  }
  return server, password
}
```

Rewriting the same method with redigo and https://github.com/soveran/redisurl:

```
// Gets redis instance from configuration parameters or environment's REDISTOGO_URL.
func redis_instance() (redis_con redis.Conn, err error) {
    if os.Getenv("REDISTOGO_URL") != "" {
        redis_con, err = redisurl.ConnectToURL(os.Getenv("REDISTOGO_URL"))
    } else {
        redis_con, err = redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
    }

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Try to set a "dummy" value, panic if redis is not accessible.
    err = redis_con.Send("Set", "INIT", time.Now().UTC())

    return
}
```

and from program's main:

```
redis, err := redis_instance()

redis.Send("Set", "SOMETHING", "ELSE")

if err != nil {
    log.Critical("Cannot access Redis server")
    log.Critical(fmt.Sprintf("%s", err))
    os.Exit(2)
}
```

On logs I get the following output:

2014-09-16T18:15:10.084908+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014/09/16 18:15:10 CRITICAL003 Cannot access Redis server
2014-09-16T18:15:10.084974+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014/09/16 18:15:10 CRITICAL004 Connection error 10942

About redis access:

```
~ $ echo $REDISTOGO_URL
redis://redistogo:47███████████@hoki.redistogo.com:10███/
~ $ ping hoki.redistogo.com
bash: ping: command not found
~ $ nc hoki.redistogo.com 10███
flushdb
-NOAUTH Authentication required.
AUTH 47███████████
+OK
get XXX
$-1
set XXX 2
+OK
get XXX
$1
2
```

Comment: What happens when you use a different package like [redigo](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo)?

Comment: Haven't tried yet...

Comment: @RickyA tried and updated question

Comment: Well, sounds like firewall/routing problems with me then. Can you ssh into heroku boxes?

Comment: Can you ssh into the box and do `redis-cli -h ip.to.your.redis`

Comment: @RickyA could not redis-cli tried with netcat.